# Understanding 2D Char Array in C

Tags: c, arrays, string, sorting

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAX 100
/* run this program using the console pauser or add your own getch, system("pause") or input loop */
void sortStrings(char arr[][MAX], int n)
{
    char temp[MAX];
    int j, i;
    // Sorting strings using bubble sort
    for (j=0; j<n-1; j++)
    {
        for (i=j+1; i<n; i++)
        {
            if (strcmp(arr[j], arr[i]) > 0)
            {
                strcpy(temp, arr[j]);
                strcpy(arr[j], arr[i]);
                strcpy(arr[i], temp);
            }
        }
    }
}
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{       
    char arr[][MAX] = {"GeeksforGeeks","Quiz","Practice","Gblogs","Coding"};
    int n = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(arr[0]);
    int i;
    sortStrings(arr, n);

    printf("Strings in sorted order are : ");
    for (i=0; i<n; i++)
        printf("\n String %d is %s", i+1, arr[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

I got this code directly from GeeksForGeeks for Bubble sort "https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sorting-strings-using-bubble-sort-2/"
And I'm trying to make sense of it. I understand the basic ideology of how 2D arrays work where the first array is the index, and the second array is the contents of the index. However, I am confused as to what is happening when

```
if (strcmp(arr[j], arr[i]) > 0)
            {
                strcpy(temp, arr[j]);
                strcpy(arr[j], arr[i]);
                strcpy(arr[i], temp);
            }
```

I don't understand what arr[j] or arr[i] is referring to in arr[][MAX]

```
printf("\n String %d is %s", i+1, arr[i]);
```

I'm also confused as to what is going on in the print of arr[i] as well. Shouldn't it be identified which index containing which contents is being printed? Sorry if my questions are confusing, I am new to 2D arrays.

Comment: This might sound unhelpful, but I honestly recommend to use pen and paper and simulate an easy case.

Comment: I'd say we don't really have ideologies in programming :o

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The in-memory view of `arr` will be something like this:

```
index   0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8...............99
       +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
arr[0] |G|e|e|k|s|f|o|r|G|e|e|k|s|0|...|0|
       +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
arr[1] |Q|u|i|z|0|.....................|0|
       +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
arr[2] |P|r|a|c|t|i|c|e|0|.............|0|
       +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
arr[3] |G|b|l|o|g|s|0|.................|0|
       +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
arr[4] |C|o|d|i|n|g|0|.................|0|
       +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
```

`arr[i]` represents the string at `i`<sup>th</sup> index of array `arr` (considering the value of `i` is a valid index w.r.t to array `arr`).

> However, I am confused as to what is happening when....

Let's take an example, assume `j=2` and `i=3` and the contents of the array of strings `arr` is same as shown above (in-memory view).
The statement

```
if (strcmp(arr[j], arr[i]) > 0)
```

will be

```
if (strcmp("Practice", "Gblogs") > 0)
```

because

```
arr[j] --> arr[2] --> "Practice"
and
arr[i] --> arr[3] --> "Gblogs"
```

In this case, the `strcmp()` will return value `> 0` and the `if` condition resulting in `true` and the two strings will be swapped like this:

```
strcpy(temp, arr[j]);
```

This will copy the content of `arr[2]` (`"Practice"`) to array `temp`.
Note: `strcpy()` copies the source to destination including terminating null character.

```
strcpy(arr[j], arr[i]);
```

This will copy the content of `arr[3]` to `arr[2]`. After this both `arr[3]` to `arr[2]` will have same value i.e. `"Gblogs"`

```
strcpy(arr[i], temp);
```

This will copy the content of array `temp` to `arr[3]`. After this the `arr[3]` will have `"Practice"`.
So, after swapping the content of `arr[2]` and `arr[3]` will be

```
arr[2] --> "Gblogs"
arr[3] --> "Practice"
```

This way the strings are getting swapped in `sortStrings()` function.

Hope this clarifies your doubts.

Answer (score 1):

What other languages consider multi-dimensional arrays are implemented in C as arrays of arrays.  For example, an array int foo[3][3] is implemented as an array of size 3 whose elements are of array type (an array of size 3 of int type).

Putting aside that array expressions are converted to pointers in parameters, what is happening in the example is that arr[i] and arr[j] are referring to the arrays of size MAX of char type at offsets i and j of array arr, thus passing arrays to the functions strcmp and strcpy to use to compare the strings stored in those arrays.

Comment: And the arrays passed to the functions `strcmp` and `strcpy` -- had better be *nul-terminated* as "*string*" functions do not accept arrays as arguments -- unless they are properly nul-terminated.

Comment: Nice catch.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

So a 2D array is a contiguous block of memory that is not demarcated by the language as such. When you refer to arr[i] it assumes the string to start from arr[i] which in terms of memory location is (arr + (i-1) * MAX).